# How create a installable msi package for my java project?

Tags: java, database, deployment, installation, shortcut-file

This installer will first check if jvm is present on the system or not. If not then it will first install the jvm. After that it will include the java code (may be in jar) alongwith the database used. And finally it will create a desktop shortcut and make changes to registry as other s/w does.

Comment: (Possibly) Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184060/java-application-installers

Comment: Use `deployJava.js` to check for the appropriate JRE versions, then (install the DB and add a desktop shortcut and/or menu item and) launch it with [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (supplied by Oracle, works on Windows, Mac & *nix).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to decide on a setup authoring tool. Here is a list which can get you started:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Advanced Installer is one of the tools which has a [dedicated Java project type](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java.html).

To detect and install JVM, you can add it as a prerequisite. This is done differently for each setup tool.