# Java Standalone executable for windows

Tags: java, executable

Is it possible to run a java application without JDK installed on Windows?
Maybe there is a way to wrap the libraries inside it

Comment: Might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe

Answer (score 0):

Without a JDK yes, but without a JRE no - assuming the distributed Java application is a .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

The client machine need to have the JRE installed.

There are some ways to embed the JRE and JVM inside your app with [avian](http://oss.readytalk.com/avian/)

Take a look in another thread as well:

[Packaging Java apps for the Windows/Linux desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720/packaging-java-apps-for-the-windows-linux-desktop?rq=1)

[Embed a JRE in a Windows executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258932/embed-a-jre-in-a-windows-executable)