# How do I make windows applications using Java?

Tags: java

I'm a noob at this but iv been practicing a lot of Java and doing stuff with data structures and what not but I have no idea how to start making actual windows applications... Can someone point me to where I can learn this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, "Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow." Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for a list of things that are on topic.

Comment: Consider looking at [Java's `swing` library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/); that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Good question, wrong place though. Try  [Creating and Running Your First Java Application](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html)

Comment: Do some research into Swing and/or JavaFX

Comment: @MadProgrammer. We meet again :P. I was gonna recommed JavaFX over Swing. Swing is too out dated.

Comment: @LittleChild The lack of platform look and feel is the major killer for me. Media support in FX is better then Swing, but I could just jvlc :P, web view is better then `JEditorPane`, but I've never tried displaying web content in Swing, so not a big deal for me. So apart from "skinning", which isn't that important to me to be frank (other then providing platform look and feel for better user acceptance), it's not a major draw card to me. Unfortunately, I think JavaFX is to little to late, with mobile and web development been the majority of new development in the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by windows applications?

1. If you mean an application with windows, in the sense that you want an application with a GUI, then you should check out the [resources from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) on using Java Swing to start with. Other options include JavaFX or AWT.
2. It is worth noting that there are command line applications. There is no definition of an "application" as specifically something that has a GUI. If you don't know how to make even a small command-line-runnable program in Java, you definitely need to start at the very beginning of the Java tutorials. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html) is the Oracle tutorial on basic compiling and running, which applies to Windows as well. The DOS shell commands can be run in Command Prompt.
3. If you mean specifically how to package Java applications for Microsoft Windows, you should look at [how to make JAR files and batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file). Optionally, you can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720/packaging-java-apps-for-the-windows-linux-desktop) on SO. Brian Kelly's answer is really complete and teaches you exactly how to make an easy-to-use executable and installer.